# valums fileupload - works in Chrome but not in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, file-upload

Here is the code

**js**

```
$(window).load(function(){
        //File Uploader
        function createUploader(){ 
          var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
          element: document.getElementById('fileUploaderButton'),
          action: 'upload.php',
          debug: true
        }); 
        createUploader();       
}
```

**the DOM after the uploader has been created**

```
<button id="fileUploaderButton" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
    <div class="qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area" style="display: none;">
        <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button" title="Upload photo" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">
        Upload photo
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0pt; top: 0pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
        </div>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>
    </div>
</button>
```

If I click on the '.qq-uploader' div, the file browser pop ups but only in Chrome. The #fileUploaderButton's cursor is pointer, but qq-uploader's id normal. The qq-uploader div is smaller than the button.  In Chrome, when the mouse is over the qq-uploader the cursor changes. In Internet Explorer or Firefox, it doesn't, even though Firebug shows that the element is there.

Comment: It could be because of 'font-size: 118px;'. Try to change it inline to 'font-size: 0px;' and tell if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it changing the container element. If the DOM element you are trying to transform in an uploader (`button#fileUploaderButton` in your case) is a button it will not work. If you use a `div`or `span` it will work, or at least it worked for me.
In your case, HTML:

```
<div id="fileUploaderButton">Upload</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function createUploader(){ 
      var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
      element: document.getElementById('fileUploaderButton'),
      action: 'upload.php',
      debug: true
    }); 
    createUploader();       
}
```